# Divide by zero error encountered, but should be excluded by CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, divide

I have the following code and I am getting an error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN SUM([monthly_qty]) = 0 THEN 999 
ELSE ROUND(SUM([monthly_buy] * ([monthly_markup]+100)/100),2) * SUM([monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty]) END as [monthly_total]
FROM [xxxxx].[dbo].[quote_items] WHERE docid='10152'
```

The field that is causing the error is the second [monthly_qty], just before the END of the CASE statement.

```
SUM([monthly_qty] / **[monthly_qty]**)
```

The value of monthly_qty is zero, so the error makes sense, but I am confused as this field is inside the CASE statement, so the expected result is 999

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: fyi `case` is an *expression* not a statement.

Comment: Your logic has `SUM([monthly_qty])` in the first branch of the `case` but the failure is the unsummed value of `monthly_qty`. You need a case *inside* the `sum`.

Comment: Why do you use `SUM([monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty])` at all? The result is an error (if `monthly_qty` is zero) or `1` (for non-zero values of `monthly_qty`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand reason of some parts of your code like this:

```
SUM([monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty])
```

The result is error when [monthly_qty] = Zero, And 1 for non zero.

Anyway, You can set a default value When "monthly_qty" is zero:

```
IIF([monthly_qty]= 0,'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE', [monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty])
```

Then:

```
SUM(IIF([monthly_qty]= 0,'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE', [monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a read at [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), there is an example of your case under Remarks.

> The CASE expression evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
> with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. In some
> situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE expression
> receives the results of the expression as its input. Errors in
> evaluating these expressions are possible. Aggregate expressions that
> appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE expression are evaluated first,
> then provided to the CASE expression. For example, the following query
> produces a divide by zero error when producing the value of the MAX
> aggregate. This occurs prior to evaluating the CASE expression.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple.  This code:

```
SUM([monthly_qty]) = 0
```

Does not prevent a divide-by-zero in this code:

```
SUM([monthly_qty] / [monthly_qty])
```

The expressions are different.

The simplest solution (and essentially the "standard" approach) is to use `NULLIF()`:

```
SUM([monthly_qty] / NULLIF([monthly_qty], 0))
```

However, I wonder if you really intend:

```
SUM([monthly_qty]) / NULLIF(SUM([monthly_qty]), 0)
```